# How to trigger callback function between Flask-SocketIO server and C# client?

Tags: python, c#, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Hey I'm writing a Python Flask application that among other purpose has to communicate with C# code. In practice a user will use the Flask application to send data with Flask-SocketIO. The C# client code will receive this data and tell the Python server that data has been received. For this purpose I want to wait for a callback function and freeze the Flask application some seconds till the callback is triggered and the program is released.

This mechanism works well when I'm using Python client (that use SocketIO library), but the same mechanism doesn't work with C# client (I've tried some libraries like SocketIoClientDotNet and SocketIO4Net). With C# data are received but the callback is not triggered in Flask app, so the app doesn't know that the data are correctly received.

So my question is: is there a manner to trigger the callback function in Flask-SocketIO server while I'm working with C# client?

The Flask-SocketIO server code is the following:

```
....
elif from_who=="improve":

    ev = threading.Event()
    socketio.emit('send data event', {'data': session["IC_to_plc"]}, callback=ack)  
    ev.wait(30)  # blocks until ev.set() is called or 30 seconds expired

    if ev.is_set():
        ev.clear()
        flash("DATA SENDED TO PLC")
        return render_template("improve_calibration/IC_2.html")
    else:
         ev.clear()
         flash("NOT POSSIBLE TO CONNECT TO PLC.")
         return render_template("improve_calibration/IC_2.html")
```

The callback function is:

```
def ack():
    nonlocal ev
    ev.set()  # unblock HTTP route
```

The C# "on event" function is (SocketIOClientDotNet library):

```
socket.On("send data event", (data) =>
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(data);
    //How to inform the server with a callback that data is correctly received without emitting another 
    //event?
}
```

Comment: The callback mechanism is a standard part of the Socket.IO specification, not something specific to Flask-SocketIO. Callbacks are implemented with the ACK packet type. You need to find out how to issue this packet type from your C# client.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have imagined this mechanism. In all cases, have you some ideas for issue the callback method?